# Не могу сдвинуть элемент относительно себя самого

Tags: веб-программирование, веб-дизайн

Подскажите, что делать. Для span пишу transform: translateY (-50%); Браузер ругается Invalid property value. Почему так?

Answer (score 1):

Надо убрать пробел между translateY и (-50%). Вот так:

```
translateY(-50%);
```